# Why got 320 code in http testing on validation error?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing

In laravel 10 app I have a test method :

```php
public function testAdded()
{
    // Test Data Setup
    $tagModel = Tag::factory()->make([]);  // model only in memory

    // Test Action
    // $tagModel->name = '';
    $response = $this
        ->post(route('tags.store'), $tagModel->toArray());
    $response
        ->assertStatus(201); 

    // READ TAG CREATED ABOVE
    $insertedTag = Tag::getBySearch(search: $tagModel->name, partial: false)
        ->first();

    $this->assertNotNull($insertedTag, 'Inserted tag not found');
    $this->assertEquals(
        $insertedTag->name,
        $tagModel->name,
        'Name read is not equal name on insert'
    );
}
```

And it works ok, until I uncommented line

```php
$tagModel->name = '';
```

I got the error:

```
 ├ Expected response status code [201] but received 302. 
   ├ Failed asserting that 201 is identical to 302.        
   ├                                                       
   ├ The following errors occurred during the last request:
   ├                                                       
   ├ The name field is required.                           
   │
```

I got a validation error message, but why code is 302?

I read in net:

> The HTTP response status code 302 Found is a common way of performing
> URL redirection.  The HTTP/1.0 specification (RFC 1945) initially
> defined this code, and gave it the description phrase "Moved
> Temporarily" rather than "Found".

I expecte error 400(bad rerquest)

On route 'tags.store' control action is assigned with common Request class as :

```php
public function store(CreateTagRequest $request)
{
       try {
        $tag = $this->tagCrudRepository->store(data: $request->only('name'));
        return response()->json(['tag' => (new TagResource($tag))], 201);
    } catch (\Error | \Exception $e) {
        \Log::info($e->getMessage());
        return response()->json([
            'error_message' => $e->getMessage(),
        ], 500);
    }
```

and common array of rules in above class :

```php
[
    'name' => [
        'required',
        'string',
        'max:100',
    ],
]
```

Why I got 302 code? Is my test invalid?

Comment: Are you working with JSON requests ?

Comment: as @PsyLogic said, you are getting a redirection because it is going back to the original page to display the errors, so if you are expecting a JSON response (AJAX/API response), use `->postJson` not `->post`

Comment: Yes, I added code in function store. Do you mean to use postJson in public function testAdded() ?

Comment: Yes, here's a doc for testing JSON in Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-tests#testing-json-apis

Comment: Yes with postJson method I got 422 code. Could you please to write your remark as answer  and I will accespt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments you seems sending JSON Requests:

instead of `post()`:

```php
$response = $this
            ->post(route('tags.store'), $tagModel->toArray());
```

use `postJson()`:

```php
$response = $this
            ->postJson(route('tags.store'), $tagModel->toArray());
```

More Information in the [Laravel Doc - Testing JSON APIS](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-tests#testing-json-apis)